# How to combine a bunch of get statements into a method?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have the following code and I don't like how `get` statements looks like. Is it possible to somehow move it out into a separate method?
I want to make a method more readable.

```
params = get_news_params_validator.document

keywords = params.get('keywords')
statuses = params.get('status')
sources = params.get('source')
from_time = params.get('from_time')
to_time = params.get('to_time')
offset = params.get('offset')
limit = params.get('limit')

query = SearchQuery(
statuses=statuses, sources=sources, text=keywords, from_time=from_time, to_time=to_time)

items = await self._news_feed_service.search(query=query, limit=limit, offset=offset)
```

Comment: Apart from `text=keywords`, you almost have an exact match in parameter name to entry name. I'd be tempted to `SearchQuery(**params)` after fixing that up

Comment: Did you try extracting a method? What happened?